# WebSQL injection prevention with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, cordova

I've search around but not found an answer to this one.

Is there a function in Javascript similar to PHP's `mysql_real_escape_string` to make safe user inputs before writing them to a WebSQL database?

If not, does anyone know of a custom made function out there that I could use?

UPDATE:
So it seems like there is no native function, so I have written:

```
function sql_real_escape_string(val){
    var val = val.replace('"','&quot;');
    val = val.replace('\'','&rsquo;');
    return val;
}
```

Are there any other characters that I should be replacing to be on the safe side?

Comment: WebSQL is deprecated and work was stopped on the spec 2 years ago.  You should use [Indexed DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_Database_API) instead.

Comment: He did use the "phonegap" and "cordova" tags, so I'm thinking Indexed DB is not an option as there's no support on Android or iOS.  I'd definitely agree with you otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

The best answer to handling user input when inserting into databases is to employ paramaterization.  The Web SQL API supports this:

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (?, ?)', [id, userValue]);
});
```

Instead of this:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (1, "user-entered value")');
});
```

Comment: I'm new to this Phonegap malarky. I've amended my code and will be doing this in future though. Thanks for the heads up.