# Why should a WebSQL database be protected against SQL injection, if it can be edited with the development console?

Tags: html, sql-injection, client-side, web-sql

I am developing a client-side only web application for learning purpose, using WebSQL to store and query data, and Javascript to process it. WebSQL is not mantained anymore, but the question may be valid for all client side databases.

In the [proposed specification for WebSQL](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#sql-injection) from the W3C, §8.5 recommends a specific syntax (parameterized queries using ? as placeholder for values) to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Given that the user is free to modify the Javascript code used in the web page, including SQL statements (or alter the database using the development Console or other browser tools) why should the program be prepared to avoid SQL injections?

I found three StackOverflow questions related to SQL injection in WebSQL, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148599/), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597265/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10031717) but none of them highlights why SQL injection is a concern on client side databases.

May someone else has a clear motivation, why SQL injection is a concern on client side databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL injection makes sense when considering unwanted third party operations on the database.

A client-side web application involves:

- the developer, who designs the database and SQL statements;
- the user, who can modify them using browser tools;
- *third-party scripts*, such as libraries, which cannot access the application database.

Actually, databases are specific to one origin, so that a script cannot open a database belonging to an other origin:

> 5. If no database with the given name from the origin *origin* exists, then create the database

(§4.1 of the [WebSQL W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#databases))

A third party attack script may use the DOM of the page to fill in form inputs with attack code, which will be injected when the form is submitted (possibly by the attacker itself, calling the `submit()` method of the form element). To avoid this, use parameterized queries: user input will never be interpreted as SQL code.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that "an SQL injection attack" is *distinct* from a "I'm gonna modify the program, or better yet, just write my own" attack.

Yes, you are entirely correct in observing that a user can do anything he wants to, to a database *and* to software source-code that winds up on *his* computer. But, this is not an "SQL injection."

"SQL injection," I think, represents any case where *an outsider* effectively modifies the database structure or content *from the outside,* and **without** directly modifying the source-code or supplying new source-code of his own.

It could well be argued, as essentially you just *did,* that SQL injection is much less likely to occur with regard to a database that exists only on the **client** computer. I think that your argument is sustained. But, I don't think that this is a successful argument for abandoning the use of parameters. I flatly recommend that one should *never* insert literal, externally-provided values into any SQL string, "period."

Comment: Thank you. I did not accept your answer because I did not have enough knowledge about web application architecture to understand it. However, your mention of a possible "outsider" headed me toward my solution.

Comment: Excellent!  Glad you found your answer!  *(Care to edit your post, say, to tell us a bit more about what you finally did? Would love to read it...)*

Comment: As the last sentence suggests, I finally used the placeholder syntax (something like `executeSQL("INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES (?)", [name], success, error)`). I am also more careful in respect to global variables, in order to avoid giving access to a function that alters the database to third-party scripts. However, I feel too inexperienced to advise any coding practice in my answer, and even to mark it as accepted without approval from experienced client-side developers.

Comment: I would suggest that you "accept" the answer, and that you already have more experience than you seem to give yourself credit for!  :-)